# Connecting MongoDB to MERN app

Tags: mongodb, express, react-native, electron, mern

I am in the process of trying to connect my MongoDB to my MERN web application and was wondering the best resource for information on this type of thing. Basically, I have a MERN web app, electron desktop app, and react native mobile app that I am trying to all connect to one MongoDB, but I can't find any information on this that directly answers how it should be wired. I can provide more details if needed.

Comment: are they all the same APP just different platforms? are they all suppose to be the same DB?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are using the database username and password not the account username and password from Mlab.

In MLab, formerly MongoLab, do the following:

1. Navigate to Users
2. Add Database User
3. Choose your username and password

Now you can test this on the shell with `mongo ds061374.mlab.com:61374/yourdb -u <dbuser> -p <dbpassword>`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have already signed up to mongodb and created a project there.
Below is the integration process to get your MERN application connected to MongoDB online cluster.

Make sure you have the following libraries installed **dotenv, mongoose.**

1. Create a folder in your project root directory that will hold your configuration file, Eg *config_folder*
2. Create a .js file, Eg *dbConnnect.js*
3. Create a create a dotenv file to hold the key for your MongoDB cluster by just creating a fine file on your project root folder and name it *.env*. **NOTE** no prefix required while naming this file.
4. login to your MongoDB and navigate to Projects, select your project then navigate to Databases -> Clusters -> connect -> connect your application -> copy the connection string.
5. Navigate back to your .env file and create a variable and paste the connection string as shown below.

```js
MONGODB_URI = 'your_connection_string_from_mongoDB'
```

6. Inside dbConnect.js add the following code.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const dbConnect = async() => {
  try {
    const connected = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,
      useFindAndModify: false
    });
    console.log(`Connected ${connected.host}`)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`error : ${error.message}`)
  }
}
module.exports = {
  dbConnect
}
```

7. Now you need to call the above block in your server file using the code below.

```js
const { dbConnect } = require('./config/dbConnect')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
dotenv.config()
dbConnect();
```

That's the end of the integration process. It worked for me and I hope it'll help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect your MongoDB with the MERN app you can use the mongoose package for that, let me tell you the steps.
Packages you will need : **mongoose,nodemon,express**

Note*:- Make sure you know how to use `Mongo Atlas`.

**1- Step 1-** create **db.js** file in your main directory.

```js
//import mongoose
    const mongoose = require("mongoose")

    //make connection variable
    const connection = mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.en0mzco.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority")

//the username and password will be the same as your cluster username and password.

//export the connection variable
module.exports={
connection
}
```

**2- Step 2-** Create **index.js** file for the server

```js
//import express
const express = require("express")

//import connection from db.js
const {connection} = require("./db.js")

//define post
const port = 4000

const app = express()

//Start server code
app.listen(port,async()=>{

  try{
  //mongo db all operations are done in an async manner so make sure you use async/await
    await connection
    
    //on the successful connection this msg will show in your terminal
    console.log("Connected to db")

  }catch(err){
  
    console.log(err)
  
  }
  
  console.log("Server is runnig on port number",port)

})
```

**3- Step 3-** Make sure you add this line to your **package.json** inside **scripts**

```
"server":"nodemon index.js"
```

//Now run the server by running this command in your terminal

```
npm run server
```

Also, I am putting my youtube video for full stack web development, where you will get all the processes of how to do all the setup.
[Youtube Link: Fullstack web development in 1hour](https://youtu.be/Xz-tX0EUqEo)